# Redefine a function when it's not available otherwise use the origin function

Tags: javascript

There is a function I need to use in some.js. But file is 
not available in some situation.

```
<head><script src="some.js">
//do something here
//function a(){};
</script></head>
```

When it's not available, I want to redefine the function.

How to detect if some.js is available or not and how to redefine the function only when it's not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "redundancy" and is quite a common pattern:

```
a = window.a || function() {
    // define a if it wasn't defined already
};
```

Perhaps the most well-known example is in event handling:

```
e = e || window.event;
```

Comment: Good ,Would this have some browser restrictions ?

Comment: Nope, none at all. It's basic syntax.

Comment: Thanks,does it also work for other types like array?

Comment: It works for basically anything... just so long as the name is known to be unique (so `a` would be a bad idea for a name - but `e` is okay in the event handling example because it's the argument to the function which may or may not be defined)

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 , Take console and ensure that javascript is loaded propery, if it is not properly loaded,Specify the physical path of js file properly.

Comment: For some reason the net connect  is down so no access to any outsie js

Answer (score -1):

in your some.js

```
SomeJs=true
```

when you want to call the function

```
a=(SomeJs==true)? a:function{
//define your function
};
```